# ASP.Net CPU 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, profiler, ants

I have a fairly large and complex ASP.Net application which uses ASP.Net / C# 3.5 / SQL Server 2005 / LINQ to SQL.  When a single user is using the system it runs very quickly, however once we start getting half a dozen users submitting at once it the CPU hits 100%.  I have tuned the application as much as I know how to using ANTS Profiler and finding weak points in the code, however the profiler points out that over 2/3 of the CPU usage is in the Transition to manage code...  Does anyone have any tips on how to combat this?

Comment: There is very little detail there - all we have is "it uses too much CPU". Without knowing more about how your app works, etc, this may be impossible to answer.

Comment: What is configuration of test machine on which its installed ? Provide more details to increase possibility to get answers.

Comment: The application is a dynamic form builder with workflow.  So it's building up a string representation of the form and using HttpHandlers to process the user from form to form.  It's Windows Server 2003 and it's a very beefy box, so shouldn't stress under the pressure.

Comment: Quad Core Xeon processor 5500, 24 gig ddr3 memory and 1Tb h/drive.

Comment: `Transition To Managed Code` implies moving from unmanaged to managed code e.g. C/C++ code calling into .NET code. So there could be something more in depth hood causing this i.e. IIS which is hosting the site. Have you been able to replicate this problem using another server? Is this a live server you;re getting the issue? In that case, is there a dev server you used - did you get the same problem?

Comment: I have a set of selenium tests which try to go through the site with about 30 simultaneous users.  I have run this on a live box & dev box through IIS and also on WebDevServer.  I get the same result, which is why I've avoided looking at IIS as the cause.  But like I say ANTS profiler is showing that the majority of the load is with the Transition To managed Code.

Comment: OK, so from the two cases you mention, Selenium is used. It's not too far fetched to maybe look into a possible Selenium issue here? Might be worth a Google!

Comment: Selenium is running on a different machine from the host, also I only created the selenium test because I was aware this was a problem.

Comment: Do you have any third party component i.e. controls, software lock... if yes, test the application without it.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919791

Comment: Thanks for this, very interesting tool, unfortunately this tool only runs for diagnostics in x86, you can do the analysis part on a 64bit machine but the tool doesn't enable debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some performance analysis to figure out the root cause.

Try out this tool, it is a great one [ developed by an Architect in CLR team]

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28567#instructions

It should help you find the issue